# Xpath is not working in IE11 but working in both Chrome and Firefox in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

My xpath is like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), '02-05 04:19:35 
PST')]//following-sibling::td//following-sibling::td//following- 
sibling::td//following-sibling::td//following-sibling::td//following- 
sibling::td//input[@type='image']")).click();
```

Above xpath worked successfully in Firefox and Chrome but in IE11 I am getting the below error

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unable to locate an element with the XPath expression.
```

How to resolve it?
Do complex paths work in IE?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and the error stack trace.

Comment: Can u add html content displayed in IE.Please make sure you have provided all details in the question.